# Sending a java thread over HTTP protocol

Tags: java, multithreading, http

Is it possible to send a Java thread instance in an HTTP request?

Comment: It isn't possible to send a thread anywhere.

Comment: NO! ...........................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  A Java thread cannot be serialized, and therefore it cannot be sent outside of the JVM in which it was originally created.

(For a moment, just *imagine* what would be involved in moving a thread from one JVM to another.  What about the static variables it might refer to?  What about the other threads that it might to interact with?  The problem is intractable.)

---

> Actually I am working on clustered servers and want to execute my some threads(defined Jobs and other heavy task) on one server(called it back office node). So is there any way to do that.

OK, so that's a different problem.  You actually need to execute tasks remotely, not pass threads.  ('Cos you can't pass threads.)

Yes, there are many ways to send tasks to be executed elsewhere ... in the general sense.  What you need to do is to express the task or task description in a form that can be serialized in some way (Java Object serialization, JSON, XML, etcetera) and then pass the serial form to the server that is going to execute it.  The server would be responsible for managing the thread that does the execution.

<sup>Caveat: This is not going to work well if the task is needs to refer to a whole lot of data / objects on the machine where you formulated the task.  That is going to involve serializing / passing all of the data OR figuring out some way for the backend to "call back" to get the specific data items that a task needs.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Stephen....  Actually I am working on clustered servers and want to execute my some threads(defined Jobs and other heavy task) on one server(called it back office node). So is there any way to do that.